# Reactjs unit testing : How to cover the code in useEffect hook? Using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I am using a coverage report generator to automatically check the lines of unit testing coverage in files in the Pull request checks, etc.

However using Jest and Enzyme, I am unable to cover the `useEffect()` code which is affecting the coverage % as shown below. How can I cover the lines in `useEffect` hook? Is this possible in Jest/Enzyme?

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as text instead screenshot.

Comment: I wanted to highlight the "uncovered" part of the code i.e the part highlighted with red color which isn't possible by posting only code

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the value of `filtersState.isDefaultAmrSet`.